# My Wordpress admin Lost All admin option, roles & privileges?

Tags: plugins

My website has been hacked 
and the hacker remove many option from database ? Try many solutions but no fix

like sit :

```
wp_capabilities 
to
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

But not working still many pages is disappear !

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can talk with your hosting provider to restore your database and files from a backup. There should be an automatic backup.

The backup period depending from your hosting plan.

Comment: thank you for your reply .. it look the only available backup is after infected !
so i tried this before also update wordpress to 5.0.2  by FTP